# How to make system fast

Tags: screenshot

[image]

@heynnema
I used to work on my laptop by opening chromium 3 tabs , firefox 1 tab(to run micrsoft teams) and two notepads. I have 2gb ram, dual core processor. Do above tasks makes my laptop slow? Whenever I navigate browsers by clicking Alt+tab Windows opening speed slows down. Pls suggest ideas to speed up.

I have asked above question . You asked to do below:

Edit your question and show me free -h and swapon -s and sysctl vm.swappiness and cat /etc/fstab. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. – heynnema May 29 at 17:36

I had attached screenshot with above command results .

Comment: Do not start a new Question while the old one is not fixed: [System slows down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341440/system-slows-down)

Comment: I don't know how to ask the question to a specific person instead of asking here in public. Is there a way to ask specifically to @heynnema?

Comment: 1. Buy maximal amount (> 4 Gb) of RAM which is supported by your CPU and chipset. 2. Buy SSD. 3. Install flavour with lower resources consumption - one of Xubuntu, Lubuntu or MATE desktops.

Comment: -1: Your previous question was about an EOL release of Ubuntu, so this question seems like an attempt to skirt site policy. If your question meets site guidelines, you should edit to make the changes very clear. Were you running a supported release of Ubuntu, the answer would be "*OF COURSE running two web browsers simultaneously with only 2GB of RAM is going to slow your system! There is no magic solution -- just the two obvious solutions*"

Comment: Either add RAM, or you can try to increase your swap partition /dev/sda5 to 4G. You could also try lubuntu or xubuntu which require less resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Lubuntu minimal version from [here](https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ubuntu-minimal-install) if you know what you are doing. I also have 2gb ram and dual core processor. Under no load, Lubuntu minimal version uses only 300 mb ram. I use chrome and I`ve tested loading 7 tabs which use a lot of resources (like youtube, amazon prime, maps, pinterest etc.) along with running file manager and system monitor. Under such loads, it uses only 1.4 Gb ram and I can switch between tabs and applications easily without any lags.

Comment: Thanks, @Master_Nachi, N0rbert, FedonKadifeli